# Jquery Dropzone dynamically change POST location

Tags: jquery, dropzone.js

I have an issue regarding Dropzone.js, I am looking to be able to change the post URL dynamically such as :

```
window.onload = function() {
  myDropzone = new Dropzone("#my-awesome-dropzone", {
    url: "upload_file.php"
  });
  myDropzone.on("complete", function(file) {
    myDropzone.removeFile(file);
  });
}
```

Where you see  url: "upload_file.php", I would like to change this property as and when I need to, this to enable me to change the path that files are stored so i can do something similar to:

```
url: "upload_file.php?path=/path/to/folder/"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sorted...

```
Dropzone.options.myDropzone = {
  init: function() {
    this.on("processingfile", function(file) {
      this.options.url = "/some-other-url";
    });
  }
};
```

from: https://github.com/enyo/dropzone/wiki/Set-URL-dynamically

Comment: for those looking at answers, it is "processing", not "processingfile".

Answer (score 6):

The provided answers are incomplete without combining them. The one from the OP is the recommended way provided by the creator of dropzone.

```
Dropzone.options.myDropzone = {
  init: function() {
    this.on("processing", function(file) { // was processingfile
      this.options.url = "/some-other-url";
    });
  }
};
```

This can be seen in the [Wiki](https://github.com/enyo/dropzone/wiki/Set-URL-dynamically) and [#94](https://github.com/enyo/dropzone/issues/94).

However, a more dynamic possibility is to use `Dropzone.options.myDropzone.options.url`. Obviously this is very extensive and can be pulled in a few different ways.

One being:

```
// assuming you have autodiscover off or you are using the whole body as a dropzone
Dropzone.options.myDropzone = new Dropzone(document.body, {
    url: '/default/url',
    ...
});

var myDropzone = Dropzone.options.myDropzone, url = "Your url";

function doSomething(dropzone, url){
    dropzone.options.url = url
}

doSomething(myDropzone, url)
console.log(myDrozone.options.url);
```

I currently prefer the second approach, but the first is obviously useful in its own ways.

Answer (score 2):

Just use

```
Dropzone.options.myDropzone.options.url = "Your url";
```

Comment: It may be, but I'm not the one who has an answer for this, I've just formatted the code, if you know the answer, then just post it as an answer. Thus, you should better comment the mistakes instead of editing the answers.

Comment: @Burak that's fine... but I edited it because I don't think I should take away from this answer by making another answer... But if you don't want to do the edit which would be better I will I guess...

Comment: As for the "better comment"... This is not the correct answer to the solution. It will create a `url` option under the dropzone you're targeting. `url` is not targeted this way in dropzone. It is targeted using `Dropzone.options.myDropzone.options.url`. I'm sorry that I created another answer as I feel the more appropriate approach would be to just edit your already sufficient answer.

Comment: @CayceK Sorry I am not sure about how the Dropzone is designed, but do you know why this actually works?

Comment: Have you used this in an environment and verified you used this code to change the url and then still upload a file to the url desired? I attempted to use this in a scenario today where I had to do just that and the url as not properly changing and was not allowing me to upload correctly. If you have seen differently maybe I did something wrong.

Comment: The other part is the fact that it should probably be mentioned when the Dropzone is first created it should have a default url even if it is just a `/`, but then can be changed shortly there after. Arguably your answer is too short to provide a full pull, but because there was a second answer that satisfied another portion I was going to leave it alone. Honestly, I wouldn't even have put a comment if the edit would have gone through as it would actually make this more correct. Looking directly at the code you can see how `url` is implemented

Comment: https://github.com/enyo/dropzone/blob/gh-pages/js/components/enyo-dropzone/lib/dropzone.js

Comment: @CayceK Oh yes, should use myDropzone.options.url,  I forgot to put the "option"

Comment: I put the downvote and want to change to an upvote if you just change that part of it. just @me