# Dropzone JS: Pass my value in my dropzone js

Tags: jquery, laravel, dropzone.js

In our application, we have wizard and we used the jquery-steps for our wizard. Once the wizard is completed there will be a modal will be pop-up, the content of the modal is my dropzone and other files that need to be upload of the users.

So what I did is, once the user finished uploading their files, in my success I'm returning some id and need to pass it to my dropzone

**PHP file**

```
function success(response) {
    studentProfile.options.autoProcessQueue = true;
    studentProfile.processQueue();
    .......
    // response.student_id;
}

var studentProfile = new Dropzone("#my-awesome-dropzone", {
    url: '/online-registration/profilePictures/updateProfilePicture?' + 'student_id=' + student_id,
    maxFilesize: 2, // MB
    maxFiles: 1,
    thumbnailWidth: 200,
    addRemoveLinks: true,
    dictDefaultMessage: "<i class='fa fa-cloud-upload'></i>UPLOAD ME",
    acceptedFiles: ".jpg, .jpeg, .png",
    autoProcessQueue: false
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    .......
});
```

I want to pass my value of my `response.student_id` in my url in the Dropzone.

Question: How do I pass the value of my response to the url of my dropzone?

Comment: Why can't you update the URL in your success function with `studentProfile.options.url = '/onlineregistration/profilePictures/updateProfilePicture?'+'student_id='+response.student_id';`

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27450429/jquery-dropzone-dynamically-change-post-location and https://gitlab.com/meno/dropzone/-/wikis/set-url-dynamically